# how to create filter new in twig template in php

Tags: php, twig

I want to add a new filter in twig template in php
For example

```
{{ "<h1>title</h1>"|raw}}
```

a new filter

```
{{ "<h1>title</h1>"|newfilter}}
```

And I don't want to use symfony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [Twig_SimpleFilter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/master/Twig_SimpleFilter.html).

```
// an anonymous function
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('newfilter', function ($string) {
    //do stuff
    return $string;
});

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

Comment: tnx OK ! AND If I define a default filter ?